# How to launch a Qt app in win console and return to prompt status?

Tags: c++, qt, command-line, windows-console

When I write an app in Qt and create an `.exe` file, it works well when launched by a double click. But I want to launch it from the command-line so that it can do something with parameters, without a need to show the GUI. Here is what I wrote:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#ifdef _WIN32
        AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
        freopen("CON", "w", stdout);
#endif
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    if(argc > 1)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
        {
            fprintf(stdout, argv[i]);
            fflush(stdout);
            fprintf(stdout, "\n");
        }
        a.exit();
    }

    else
    {
        MainWindow w;
        w.show();
        return a.exec();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What I expect is I enter something like `./console.exe -ooo`, and powershell will print the path of `console.exe` and `-ooo` and then wait for my next command.

But actually, it stops when powershell prints `-ooo`:

[image: it looks like this]

Comment: "wait for my next enter." huh?  What do you mean?

Comment: @Yakk I believe the OP wants control to return to the shell immediately after the app is launched (so that new commands can be entered in the shell), while what they get is the shell waiting for the app to finish before processing further. Think Window's `start` or Posix `&`.

Comment: @Yakk Maybe my description is confusing.I want run the .exe file without gui, it posts some warnings in console and end itself, "wait for my next enter" is like typing prompt" or "echo." in cmd.

Comment: So, after you run the command, you get the prompt again.  Then your application prints arg[0], flushes, prints a newline, prints arg[1], flushes, newline.  If you typed a new command right away, it would be interpreted by powershell.  The Qt application is *not* blocking the console, you just attached to it and have been spewing text into it.  Or that is what looks like what is happening; nothing is "wait for my next enter."